# which mysql yum repo for mysql 5.6 on EC2 Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09

Tags: php, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, mysql-5.6

we have an EC2 instance running the following

- Linux - Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09,
- Apache 2.4.6
- php 5.4.23

I need to install MySQL 5.6 but am getting confused with all the Yum repos available at
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 / Oracle Linux 5 (Architecture Independent), RPM Package
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 / Oracle Linux 6 (Architecture Independent), RPM Package
- Fedora 18, 19, 20

when i run the following shell command

```
cat /proc/version
```

it gives me

```
Linux version 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31003) (gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) )
```

so... RHEL 4 !?

If i was to take an educated guess based on
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=51647&tstart=0#194519

...it would be the RHEL 6 repo, right ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question; sounds more like an admin or general installation thing.  Might try http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com.

Comment: For reference, though... `cat /etc/redhat-release`

Comment: `cat /etc/redhat-release` doesn't work, however `cat /etc/system-release` is where i got the "Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09"

Comment: @cHao would you mind migrating this question to serverfault.com ?

Comment: Voted to move it there.  It'll take others voting to move it too, or a moderator stepping in.

Comment: If you don't have a `redhat-release` file, i'm not sure how much good any of the RHEL or Fedora RPMs would do you.  Have you tried just `yum search mysql`?  Amazon will almost certainly have a recent version of MySQL ready to install...

Comment: latest version available in `yum search mysql` is 5.5 unfortunately, hence the need for the mysql yum repo

Comment: tried the RHEL 6 repo and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried the RHEL 6 repo and it worked fine.

**UPDATE:**
to get the system info on Amazon Linux AMI try:
`cat /etc/os-release`

which should give you something simlar to:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Note the `ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"` which seems to indicate that RHEL should work fine.

In addition, apparently AMI is based on RHEL (yes that doesn't help with the version):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image#Amazon_Linux_AMI

For installation instructions see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html